# Can't change more than 1 material in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I changed my object's material by this code:

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().material = customMaterial[i];
```

But then I customized object, so now it have 3 materials. With this code:

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[0] = customMaterial[i];
GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[1] = customMaterial[i];
GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[2] = customMaterial[i];
```

...nothing changes in the object. And this appears:

[Material (Instance)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opl5o.png)

How can I change the material in the object properly?

Comment: if I use GetComponent<Renderer>().material = customMaterial[i]; with 3 materials it change only first

Comment: You are setting the same material for every sub-mesh on the gameObject, is this the desired behaviour? Does your mesh have different sub-meshes?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to make a new Array, fill it with your values. Then assign the array and that will trigger the update.